# Como usar os resultados e as variáveis de um Jupyter notebook em outro?

Tags: ipython-notebook

Suponha que exista um Jupyter notebook chamado **notebook1.ipynb** onde são calculadas diversas variáveis com resultados interessantes. Suponha então que, como parte de outra análise em outro notebook chamado **notebook2.ipynb**, seja interessante acessar as variáveis calculadas em **notebook1**. Nesse caso, como acessar essas mesmas variáveis e resultados sem ter que copiar todo o código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Jupyter possui um *comando mágico* chamado **%run** que permite chamar e executar um outro código externo de dentro do notebook que está sendo executado, guardando assim seus resultados e variáveis.

Ex:

Estando no **notebook2.ipynb**, você pode executar o comando abaixo:

```
%run "./notebook1.ipynb"
```

O Jupyter vai então executar o **notebook1** de dentro do notebook no qual você está executando esse comando e com isso vai carregar em memória todas as variáveis calculadas e mostrar todos os resultados que são mostrados normalmente em **notebook1**.

Comment: Por favor, alguém com a pontuação necessária pode adicionar a tag "jupyter" para mim nessa pergunta? Eu não tenho pontos suficientes para bem anotar essa pergunta. Muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: **Anderson**, você mesmo pode fazer isso clicando no link [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/330879/edit) que fica abaixo da pergunta.

Comment: Ele quer criar a tag. Já adianto que pelo site móvel não é possível.

Comment: Sim, a tag precisa ser criada. Na verdade, existe uma que é a ipython-notebook que eu usei que hoje não faz mais sentido visto que o projeto evoluiu e se tornou o projeto Jupyter que inclui kernels outros que não só o do IPython, como também o IJulia, e outros. Por isso a criação da tag certa seria importante.

Answer (score -2):

Há uma outra forma bem interessante também que é salvar uma variável ou qualquer outro objeto Python em um arquivo externo com o *pickle* e recuperá-la posteriormente em outro notebook ou qualquer código python.
O que o *pickle* faz é a serialização do objeto e salva em um arquivo, podendo ser feito o caminho inverso depois.

Para salvar o objeto no notebook1:

```
# define a variável
var1 = 'casa'

# importa o módulo pickle
import pickle

# salvar a variável no arquivo arquivo-var1.pkl
with open('arquivo-var1.pkl', 'wb') as arquivo:
    pickle.dump(var1, arquivo)
```

Depois para recuperar o objeto em outro notebook:

```
# importa o módulo pickle
import pickle

# salvar o conteúdo arquivo-var1.pkl em var2
with open('arquivo-var1.pkl', 'rb') as arq:
    var2 = pickle.load(arq)
```

Ressalto que não é necessário rodar novamente o notebook1. Os objetos são salvos no estado em que se encontram. Isso vale inclusive para modelos de machine learning.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Para. Já que é para fazer o I/O de um pickle melhor fazer com um JSON que pode ser aproveitado em outras plataformas.